# Server not seeing the JSON sent in javascript ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to make an ajax request in straight javascript (jQuery is not available to me) with some JSON parameters.
The javascript:

```
var params = {'ajax': true, 'albumid': albumid, 'sequencenum': sequencenum};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open("GET","viewpicture.php",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
console.log("sending request");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

In viewpicture.php, a var_dump($_GET) yields an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In short, when you make a `GET` request, `.send` is expected to have 0 params (or be `null`).
The only way to send the data through `GET` would be to append it to the URL itself.

To wit:
If you were sending in form-data, in a `POST`, the anticipation would be that `send` would contain the form-encoded data (json for json-data, etc), and the URL would just be the access point on the server.

A `GET` request is just fetching data from that access point (including query string).
See where I'm going with this?

So if you want this to work in a `GET`, you need to set your JSON as a property of a query parameter (or turn it into query params/values).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send in the request body you should use a `POST` request, however if you need to use a get request you should send the data as key value pairs in the url. e.g. `xhr.open("GET","viewpicture.php?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params)),true);` Then retrieve via `$_GET['data']`.